# Flutter issue with better_player & RawKeyboardListener

Tags: android, flutter

If I wrap BetterPlayer into RawKeyboardListener and show the BetterPlayer controls, the controls cant use with keyboard or Android TV remote control.

This is the code atm and I want to use controls if the user press the down button. Controls showing up (with language, quality, etc. selector), but cant select anything.

```
return RawKeyboardListener(
                    focusNode: FocusNode(),
                    onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
                      if (event.runtimeType == RawKeyDownEvent) {
                        switch (event.logicalKey.keyLabel) {
                          case 'Arrow Down':
                            // Open quality/language selector
                            if (_controller.controlsAlwaysVisible) {
                              _controller.setControlsAlwaysVisible(false);
                            } else {
                              _controller.setControlsAlwaysVisible(true);
                              _controller.setControlsEnabled(true);
                            }
                            break;
                          case 'Arrow Right':
                            // Rewind 15 seconds
                            if (!_controller.controlsAlwaysVisible) {
                              _controller.seekTo(
                                _controller
                                        .videoPlayerController!.value.position +
                                    Duration(seconds: 15),
                              );
                              showSnackbar(
                                  context, "15 sec >");
                            }

                            break;
                          case 'Arrow Left':
                            // Rewind 15 seconds
                            if (!_controller.controlsAlwaysVisible) {
                              _controller.seekTo(
                                _controller
                                        .videoPlayerController!.value.position -
                                    Duration(seconds: 15),
                              );
                              showSnackbar(
                                  context, "< 15 sec");
                            }
                            break;
                          case 'Select':
                            if (!_controller.controlsAlwaysVisible) {
                              if (_controller.isPlaying() == true) {
                                _controller.pause();
                                showSnackbar(context, "Pause");
                              } else {
                                _controller.play();
                                showSnackbar(context, "Play");
                              }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                      }
                    },
                      child: BetterPlayer(controller: _controller)));
```